# Missing "Building Objects" addon in V2.79

Tags: add-on

I installed Blender V2.79 just a few weeks ago.  I cannot find "Building Objects" in the Add-ons.  Is there a way to fix this, such as downloading it?

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of this addon before.

Apparently you can download it from [this github repository](https://github.com/sftd/blender-addons-contrib/tree/master/add_mesh_building_objects) though it hasn't been updated in a while.

There's no guarantee it will work under current versions of Blender.